# Kotlin: "abstract member cannot be accessed directly" when using delegation ("by" keyword)

Tags: kotlin, delegates, overriding

This is the sample code:

```
class PurchaseHistory: MutableList<PurchaseInfo> by mutableListOf() {
    override fun add(element: PurchaseInfo): Boolean {
        // ... some code
        return super.add(element)
    }
}
```

However, I am getting `abstract member cannot be accessed directly`. When I use the original method from outside the class, I don't encounter any issues, but why can't I do the same thing from inside of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the `add` method you're trying to call is not really in `PurchaseHistory`'s super class (because it doesn't have a superclass), and thus the error tells you that you cannot just call an interface (abstract) method using `super`.

To do what you want, you can keep a handle to the object you are delegating to. For instance, you can store it as a property:

```kotlin
class PurchaseHistory(
    private val backingList: MutableList<PurchaseInfo> = mutableListOf()
): MutableList<PurchaseInfo> by backingList {
    override fun add(element: PurchaseInfo): Boolean {
        // ... some code
        return backingList.add(element)
    }
}
```

Another option is to directly extend an implementation of `MutableList` (such as `ArrayList`) instead of implementing by delegation, but that might not be an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call method from interface MutableList which is not defined.

Just make ArrayList supper of your class, and you should have good result:

```
class PurchaseHistory: ArrayList<PurchaseInfo>() {

    override fun add(element: Int): Boolean {
        // ... some code
        return super.add(element)
    }
}
```